# Is ios::in needed for ifstream's opened in binary mode?

Tags: c++, ifstream

What's the difference between these two? Isn't the `in` flag object thing redundant? Thanks.

`std::ifstream file1("one.bin", std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);`

`std::ifstream file2("two.bin", std::ifstream::binary);`

Comment: erm... from the docs I don't suppose it is redundant; and it's worth 30 seconds to ... try :)

Comment: Why is it relevant if its binary or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs on `ifstream` class constructor:

> **binary**    (binary) Consider stream as binary rather than text.
>   **in**    (input) Allow input operations on the stream.

So when reading from a file, I would use `std::ifstream::in` flag not because it's required (or not) but because it would be a good programming practice to let a programming interface know what you are going to use it for.

Edit:
The following is taken from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/, about `open()` member function though (but the constructors in the code in the question probably call `open()` copying the mode flags without modification).

> **class:**    **default mode parameter**
>   ofstream: ios::out
>   ifstream: ios::in
>   fstream:  ios::in | ios::out
>
> For ifstream and ofstream classes, ios::in and ios::out are
>   automatically and respectively assumed, even if a mode that does not
>   include them is passed as second argument to the open() member
>   function.

Nevertheless, many examples over the Web use `ifstream::in` when showing a construction of an `ifstream` object. Could really be some kind of a superstition practice, instead of a programming one.

Comment: @ Naveen: Do I need to let `ifstream` know I want to use it for _input_? I could just as well use plain `fstream` then - which is why I posted this question in the first place. :)

Comment: Yeah, good point :P I've already gotten softer on it in the edit.

Comment: Guys, stop upvoting my answer because it doesn't really give much of an answer, just expresses a personal opinion plus gives some indirectly related info on `open()` member function. However, it doesn't mean I want it to get downvoted =)

Comment: Well if it happens for `open()` I think it's reasonably safe to assume it also happens for the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

`binary`, in this case, only refers to the method of reading or writing. In regular mode on windows, `'\n'` is translated to `'\r''\n'`. This can affect both reading and writing, so binary mode turns this off.  `out|binary` makes just as much sense as `in|binary`

Answer (score 1):

I can't find authoritative documentation online.

**Edit** I can't even find a proper reference in my copy the [Josuttis Book](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/), 8th printing. *It should have been in section 13.9 pp. 627-631*

Empirical evidence suggests it is redundant IFF none of std::ios::in or std::ios:out are passed:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(args[0], std::ios::binary);
    std::cout << ifs.rdbuf() << std::flush;

    return 0;
}
```

Succeeds:

```
test | md5sum
md5sum test
```

show the same hash sum.

---

```
    // ...
    std::ifstream ifs(args[0], std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

---

will fail (zero bytes output)

```
test | wc -c  # shows 0
```

Answer (score 0):

From [cplusplus.com reference page](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/), **there is no difference.**

> `in` is always set for `ifstream` objects (**even if explicitly not set** in argument *mode*).

It's the same for `ofstream`. Therefore, you don't need to set `std::ios::in` for `ifstream` or `std::ios::out` for `ofstream`, even if you have set `std::ios::binary` which omits the `in/out` mode.